# Need help: Chart Web part and list header style in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, charts, customization

I have 2 questions here, please help me.

First one, i would like to know on what basis Chart Web part y-axis columns are taken. why i could not get my own site columns in Y-axis. Please refer the below image.[image: I need to get my own column names here. Please let me know what to do for that..]

Second question, i have created a list but when i add Description & Comments  (multiple text) fields, the text color is coming differently. The text color is not matching with the other list column names. Please let me know how to correct this..??
[image: Please give me suggestion on this..]

Thanks for your guidance & help.

Answer (score 0):

Y field will have to be numeric.  X field can be any type.  This would make sense, because if it is not numeric how will you show it in the chart?  if the column is a choice column, etc.  you can create a calculated column that reflects the original column but outputs a number.

Description and Comments are coming up as different because they cannot be sorted or filtered.  They are there to provice a visual indication to the end user.  you can ofcourse change them usign CSS/jquery...